# Tensorboard and Dropout Layers

Tags: tensorflow, merge, keras, dropout

I have a very basic query. I have made 4 almost identical(Difference being input shapes) CNN and have merged them while connecting to a Feed Forward Network of fully connected layers.

Code for the almost identical CNN(s):

```
model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', 
                                     input_shape=(batch_size[3], seq_len, channels)))
model3.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model3.add(Dropout(0.1))
model3.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model3.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model3.add(Flatten())
```

But on tensorboard I see all the Dropout layers are interconnected, and Dropout1 is of different color than Dropout2,3,4,etc which all are the same color.[image]

Comment: Can you show how you connect them?

Comment: all layers are connected using the miodel.add function as shown in the code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I had the same issue myself and just now I realized what's going on

Dropout is only applied if we're training the model. This should be deactivated by the time we're evaluating/predicting. For that purpose, keras creates a `learning_phase` placeholder, set to `1.0` if we're training the model.
This placeholder is created inside the first `Dropout` layer you create and is shared across all of them. So that's what you're seeing there!

[image]