# Understanding Keras LSTM Tensorboard Graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorboard

I am confused about the graph I am getting in Tensborboad for my Keras LSTM network. I have defined my Keras LSTM network like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(neurons, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(look_back,2)))
#model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(neurons, return_sequences=True),input_shape=(look_back,2)))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(LSTM(neurons,return_sequences=True,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))   
model.add(LSTM(20,return_sequences=False,recurrent_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
          kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),dropout=dropout,recurrent_dropout=dropout))
model.add(Dense(outputs,kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),bias_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I thought that would give me a sequential model, where each LSTM takes the output of the previous LSTM. I sort of get that. But I also get one of the LSTM layers as the input to every single subsequent layer:

[image]

In the graph, it looks like **lstm_2** feeds into every layer. I wouldn't have expected that. So my question is, is this expected? And if so, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out why it is showing like that. It turns out that Keras creates a learning_phase placeholder and it places it in the second hidden layer. The learning_phase object branches out to every single layer, but the LSTM itself does not. I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259467/tensorboard-and-dropout-layers) for more details.

Here's what the insides of my LSTM_1 layer looked like in my Tensorboard graph:

[image]

Comment: Why the placeholder  placed in the second LSTM but not the first LSTM?